# SQL Query based on occurrence of records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

After a long time, I am getting a chance to post a SQL Server question here.

I have a table variable as shown below, in SQL Server 2005. This table is populated by a stored procedure written by some other team.

This is a order processing system. Each order can be accomplished by multiple processes by various departments, based on the `OPRouteCode`.

Taking example for `OrderNo = 2`, it has two `OPRouteCode` - but both these `OPRouteCode`s are using the same processes by same departments. They are considered `equivalent` OPRouteCodes.

On the other hand, for example `OrderNo = 1`, the processes and departments vary; hence they are not equivalent.

What is the best way to select only orders that has `non-equivalent` `OPRouteCodes`.

Note: If there is only one `OPRouteCode`, it is considered as equivalent only. Non-equivalence come only if there are more than one `OPRouteCode`.

What is the best SQL Server query to get this result? I couldn't write anything working after hours of effort.

```
DECLARE @OrderProcess TABLE (OrderNo Int, 
                             OPRouteCode VARCHAR(5), 
                             Department VARCHAR(10), 
                             Process VARCHAR(20) )

--Order = 1 OPRouteCode =  '0023'
INSERT INTO @OrderProcess
SELECT 1,'0023' ,'103','Receive'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'0023' ,'104','Produce'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'0023' ,'104','Pack'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'0023' ,'105','Ship'

--Order = 1 OPRouteCode =  '0077'
INSERT INTO @OrderProcess
SELECT 1,'0077' ,'103','Receive'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'0077' ,'104','Produce'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'0077' ,'105','Ship'

--Order = 2 OPRouteCode =  '0044'
INSERT INTO @OrderProcess
SELECT 2,'0044' ,'105','Receive'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'0044' ,'106','Ship'

--Order = 2 OPRouteCode =  '0055'
INSERT INTO @OrderProcess
SELECT 2,'0055' ,'105','Receive'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'0055' ,'106','Ship'
```

**Table Variable**

[image]

**Expected Output**

[image]

Comment: Can you post your expected output?

Comment: Ive tagged this with your specific version of sql server. Unfortunately, newer versions have included some stuff that massively helps with this sort of query, but none of that will help you if someone posts an answer targetting SQL2014 for example.

Comment: @FelixPamittan  I have updated the question with expected output

Answer (score 0):

Alright I got it this time. Sorry for the wrong answer before.

```
Select OrderNo,OPRouteCode
From (
select OrderNo,OPRouteCode, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY OrderNo,Department ORDER BY Process ) 'Rnk'
from @OrderProcess
) a 
Where Rnk =2
```

Comment: Should it be `WHERE Rnk >= 2`?

Comment: @TTeeple i thought about that, but Since it is only partitioning by 2 things and using Rank, I believe it can only be rank 1 or 2 ... but I could be wrong.   Obviously using Row_Number() would change everything